# my Button cannot change a state in another react native component

Tags: react-native

Why does the following code not work? In this test I simply try to show a state of the component Board, when the Button is clicked. But I get a TypeError: undefined is not an object.

```
var board = (<Board/>);

  return (

        <View>
          { board }
          <Button
             title="Press me"
             onPress={() => Alert.alert(board.state.lastRefresh)}
           />
        </View>
  );
};
```

The Board component has this constructor:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      lastRefresh: Date(Date.now()).toString(),
    }
    ...
```

Comment: does your board render here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Board` component is something like this:

```js
import PageTwo from 'PageTwo';

export default class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lastRefresh: Date(Date.now()).toString(),
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <PageTwo lastRefresh={this.state.lastRefresh}>
                </PageTwo>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

You can access your props by this way from `PageTwo` component:

```js
export default class PageTwo extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button
                    title="Press me"
                    onPress={() => Alert.alert(this.props.lastRefresh)}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```